# Heroku is not reading Firestore credentials

Tags: api, go, heroku, google-cloud-firestore, deployment

I am working on a project where I am using `Gin` framework for API development and `Firestore` as a database. In local everything is working fine. I am able to perform CRUD operations. When I deployed the API to `Heroku`, I can see in logs that the build is successful and the application gets deployed. When I clicked on it to open it is giving the error `"Application error"`. It is because Heroku is not reading my `firestore` credentials from the `google-credentials.json` file. And I am not supposed to upload the `google-credentials.json` file as it has my credentials. For local I am reading it by giving a local file path.

controllers/users.go

```
var firestoreCredentialsLocation = "A:/Go/API_Gin/google-credentials.json"     //local  path to file

func GetUses(c *gin.Context) {

    // Use a service account
    ctx := context.Background()
    sa := option.WithCredentialsFile(firestoreCredentialsLocation)
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, sa)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    blah blah..........
    blah blah..........
    blah blah..........

    }

    c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "message": "Users returned successfully!",
    })
}
```

Error after clicking on URL:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHmJb.png)

logs:

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBgSf.png)

Can you guys tell me how can I solve this problem? What should I do so that Heroku will read my database credentials and deploy the app successfully? Also, tell me is it a good method to give the path of a .json file?
Thank you.

Comment: I also tried this one but it is not working for me.
https://devdojo.com/bryanborge/adding-google-cloud-credentials-to-heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I was reading a port value in an incorrect manner and because of that, the application crashed. Heroku's documentation for Go apps helped me.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the credentials from the file, try to get them from the environment variables.
You can check this Heroku documentation to find out how to set environment variables in Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: I already tried this approach but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Heroku google-credentials build pack [here](https://github.com/buyersight/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack) to read google-credentials from environment variables and create a credentials.json in heroku